# Show number sign at the right side of number using cell formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I need to create formatting for numbers while keeping their actual value:

- If a negative is number entered, the minus sign needs to appear on the
  right-hand side of the number.
- If a positive number is entered, the plus sign needs to be on the
  right-hand side of the number too.
- If `1` or `-1` is entered, it should show only sign.

For example `2` becomes `2+` and `-3` becomes `3-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming integers only, please try a Custom Format of:

```
0"+";0"-";"-";
```

*Re Edit:*

Select the range to be formatted (I chose N for illustration), HOME > Styles – Conditional Formatting, New Rule…, *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**

```
=N1=1
```

<kbd>Format…</kbd>, Number, Custom, Type:

```
+
```

OK, OK.

Repeat (New Rule) with formula:  `=N1=-1` and `;-`, then might as well include the other custom formats as another Conditional Formatting rule, rather than a Custom Format:

`=OR(N1>1,N1<-1)`, and `0+;0-;`

Note that the sequence in which these rules are applied may be significant.

Comment: Big thanks. Only if I specify zero, only minus sign is shown, but I do not expect to deal with zeros.

Comment: I don't believe you require the quotes for those symbols. A format mask of `0+;0-;-` or `0+;0-;0` should suffice. I try to avoid quotes in format masks as much as possible; mainly for their reuse in VBA's [Range .NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) where I don't want to hassle with quotes inside a quoted string.

Comment: Edit was done to post. Can format be configured to not show 1- or 1+ but only + or - ?